# remove an item form a position in local storage

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i want remove an item from local storage. I try this code:

```
var pos=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("position_users")));
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users"));
    if(storedNames.length===1){
    localStorage.removeItem("user_login_users");
    }else if(storedNames.length>1){
        storedNames.slice(pos,1);
        console.log(storedNames);
        
        localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(storedNames));
        alert("utente cancellato");
        window.open("onlinemoviecatalog.html");
    }}
```

where user_login_users={[name:"jack"surname:"rossi", name:"rosy",surname:"chan"]} and position_users={[0]}.User_login_users and position_users are in JSON. My code don't remove nothing. How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Slice vs Splice

1. The splice() method returns the removed item(s) in an array and slice() method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object.
2. The splice() method changes the original array and slice() method doesn’t change the original array.

Corrected code,

```js
// Using slice
storedNames = storedNames.slice(pos, pos + 1);

// Using splice
storedNames.splice(pos, 1)
```

You need to assign the output to the variable. `Slice` does not mutate the original array

Comment: tank you. How can i mutate the original array?